# How to properly implement voting on decision tree bagging method with for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I am new to python and machine learning I've tried to look at at sklear documentation for voting classifier and to be quite hones I was bot lost.

I have performed bagging for a decision tree inside a for loop, however I am stuck where I have to perform Voting to make the final decision on
each data sample, and then calculate the accuracy on the final results.

I get `TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration`.

Below is my code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.utils import resample


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.35, random_state=3)

predictions = []

for i in range(1,20):
bootstrap_size = int(0.8*len(X_train))
x_bag, y_bag = resample(X_train,y_train, n_samples = bootstrap_size , random_state=i , replace = True) 
Base_DecisionTree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=3)
Base_DecisionTree.fit(x_bag, y_bag)
y_predict = Base_DecisionTree.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)
predictions.append(accuracy)


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, VotingClassifier
votingClass = VotingClassifier(predictions)
#print(votingClass)
votingClass.fit(X_train, y_train)
confidence = votingClass.score(X_test, y_test)
print('accuracy:',confidence)
```

Comment: Can you specify which line of code is generating the error?
I'm not familiar with the Decision Tree library of sklearn but are you sure that you are passing the right set of labels in the function: Base_DecisionTree.fit(bag, y_train) ? From my understanding the bag is a subset of the original train while y_train are the labels of the original training set. I would expect that y_train would be also a subset of label matching the samples.

Comment: @Roberto Sorry about that I had pasted old code, so sorry about the confusion I've updated it. The line giving me the error is `votingClass.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: don't worry, thanks for updating it. I've posted an answer

Answer (score 2):

I  looked into the VotingClassifier from my understanding the function accepts  a set of classifier while in your case you are giving a list of accuracy. Please find a example code from the documentation of sklearn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, VotingClassifier

clf1 = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='multinomial',random_state=1)
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, random_state=1)
clf3 = GaussianNB()

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
eclf1 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr', clf1), ('rf', clf2), ('gnb', clf3)], voting='hard')
eclf1 = eclf1.fit(X, y)
print(eclf1.predict(X))
#[1 1 1 2 2 2]
np.array_equal(eclf1.named_estimators_.lr.predict(X), eclf1.named_estimators_['lr'].predict(X))
#True
eclf2 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[ ('lr', clf1), ('rf', clf2), ('gnb', clf3)], voting='soft')
eclf2 = eclf2.fit(X, y)
print(eclf2.predict(X))
#[1 1 1 2 2 2]
 eclf3 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[ ('lr', clf1), ('rf', clf2), ('gnb', clf3)], voting='soft', weights=[2,1,1], flatten_transform=True)
eclf3 = eclf3.fit(X, y)
print(eclf3.predict(X))
#[1 1 1 2 2 2]
print(eclf3.transform(X).shape)
#(6, 6)
```

EDIT

So I don't think that the function VotingClassifier is the right path to solve your task.

What you have to do is to collect all the y_predict from your for loop.
This will give you a prediction for each sample.

once that for each sample (e.g. [image: formula]) you have all the predictions (e.g [image: formula] ) you can compute the vote. The result will be the final label of the prediction ([image: formula]= Vote([image: formula])).

The accuracy is given comparing the labels predicted from the vote with the ground truth.

Comment: What I'm being asked to do doesn't seem to fit the documentation.

Comment: After finishing the “for” loop, you should have 19 different predictions for EACH sample
in your testing set. Then, Perform Voting to make the final decision on each` data sample
based on the votes of all 19 classifiers.
Finally, calculate and report the final accuracy of your Bagging (Voting) method.
Note: You do NOT need to calculate the accuracy of each one of the base classifiers in
each round of the loop! You have to just perform Voting to make the final decision on
each data sample, and then calculate the accuracy on the final result

Comment: Yes but in your code, inside the for loop, you have: 

ln12: accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)

ln13: predictions.append(accuracy)

Thais  computes the accuracy at each loop against your specifications: "Note: You do NOT need to calculate the accuracy of each one of the base classifiers in each round of the loop! You have to just perform Voting to make the final decision on each data sample, and then calculate the accuracy on the final result".